# I want to change a profile picture when i select a image

Tags: jquery

```
$('#profile_picture').on("change",function(){
     var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
```

what does the above code `!!this.files ? this.files : []` mean?

```
    if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) return; 

    if (/^image/.test( files[0].type)){ 
        var reader = new FileReader(); 
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]); 
        reader.onloadend = function(){ 
            $("#imgchange").attr("src", "+this.result+");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is used to check whether the new [FileAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File) is supported. If the new file api is not supported the file input's `files` property will undefined so `!this.files` will be false and when we add one more `!` the false will be again negated to true

```
$('#profile_picture').on("change", function () {
    // the files is a new property from the new File API, if if it is not supported assign an empty array as the value of files
    var files = !! this.files ? this.files : [];

    //if there are no files and FileReader is not supported return
    if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) return;

    if (/^image/.test(files[0].type)) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
        reader.onloadend = function (event) {
            $("#imgchange").prop("src", event.target.result);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i get result wtih long paragraph... how to get the image url to store specific location(folder) and at same time the profile picture change in front end

Comment: @Priya if you want to store the image in the server then you need to write server side code to do that

Comment: Can u tell about how to get file name,tmp location,